# Get on edit macro working on google form responses tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code that works perfect on the rest of my google sheet
but as people have started missing data when filling in the sheet i have made a google form for them to use when adding in the information

The only issue is that my "onedit" macro works on every tab except the "responses tab" from the google form

Is there any way to get this to work?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var value = e.range.getValue();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var destination = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,21);
  var destination2 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,22);
  
if(col === 1 && row > 1 && value === "NO" && destination.getValue() ===""){
    
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,21).setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-yy');
}

if(col === 1 && row > 1 && value === "YES" && destination2.getValue() ===""){
    
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,22).setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-yy');
}

}
```

Comment: What makes you think the trigger doesn't work on the `responses tab`? Please be aware that an `onEdit` trigger will only fire in user edits. If you want the script to run when a user submits a form, you should use an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) trigger instead.

Comment: I use the google form for the original data to be filled in on the sheet. I have other columns on the sheet that when edited i want the "onEdit script to run. eg the person who fills in the form is adding a task, when i complete the task i them change the status column to "yes" I want it to record a timestamp. However the come works on all the other sheets and will not work on the responses tab unless i unlink it from the form

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: When i sent to credit a new sheet to you as an example the code works... i dont know what i did wrong the first time be i re wrote the code from scratch and its now working. Thanks for the help. sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const nd = new Date();
  const dt = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), nd.getMonth(), nd.getDate());
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "NO" && sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 21).getValue() == "") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 21).setValue(nd).setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-yy');
  }
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStrart > 1 && e.value === "YES" && sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 22).getValue() == "") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 22).setValue(nd).setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-yy');
  }
}
```